# how to call a method from layout xml android

Tags: java, android

i want to get the width size of the device and put it into "android:layout_width"

i tried to do this:

> android:layout_width="GetSizeOfDevice()"

but it doesnt work...
how can i call a method from the layout xml?

by the way, GetSizeOfDevice() do:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
{
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width1 = size.x;
    return width1/4;
}
else
{
    int width1 = display.getWidth();
    return width1/4;
}
```

Comment: so?.. any success?.. did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get the width:

```
// getting the width of the display
Context context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
WindowManager window = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();
final int width = display.getWidth();
```

Then you set your new width by using `.setWidth()`:

```
yourView.setWidth(width);
```

I have tested this and **it works**. There's no need to call a method from within the layout, as [Bill Mote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617044/bill-mote) pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You guys might be missing the obvious ... if you're just going to get the width and populate the field with it then why not use layout_width="fill_parent"?  The only place you can call a method from within the layout file is android:onClick="doSomething()" and I would highly discourage that.

Comment: Well, the guy asked for it. And who knows what intricacies he's concocting in his code. But yeah... you're right about fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call java methods from xml layout.

what you are trying to do can be easily achieved by using layout `weightSum/weight` attributes.

just set weightSum for your view's parent layout group (Linearlayout, framelayout ...)  like this :

```
android:WeightSum="4"
```

and for your view set:

```
android:Weight="1"
andrpod:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

then the view will automatically scale to 1/4th of your screen width

Comment: That should be `android:weightSum` (lower-case 'w') and `android:layout_weight`